# How to generate report to PDF?

Tags: report-chart

I need generate the report to PDF. Pleas could you give any suggestion for this issue. I have created visual force page it's generated only for excel format, but I need to generate PDF format.

Comment: add <apex:page renderAs="pdf">, and your visualforce page will be rendered in PDF format

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to create pdf of your reports from standard report layout. There is an [IDEA](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BqCDAA0) posted, you can vote for it.

The only way to do it create a Visualforce page and render it as pdf.